# Raphael, make object not receive events

Tags: javascript, raphael

There is an object behind the object I am dealing with, and I don't want to click this first element, I want to click the one under it.

Is it possible to make an element in raphael stop receiving events, but still remain visible?

Answer (score 2):

Events bubble, so the object behind it will still receive the click event. Just ignore the event on the object in front. However, if the object "in front" is not a child of the object "in the back" that won't work. That is the case when you have absolutely positioned elements as Rapahel does. Your only solution would be to use  http://robertnyman.com/css3/pointer-events/pointer-events.html

```
pointer-events: none;
```

But that only works for latest FF and Chrome

Or use a hack like Randy Hall suggested where you dispatch the event your self by hiding the element that was clicked and using `elementFromPoint()`

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for this, just built something similar. What you need to do is trigger an event on the object behind the visible one. You need to trigger the event on the dom BEHIND the canvas, essentially? You'll need to work out the specifics for cross-browser, but this should get you started

```
element.onclick = function (e){ //or however you're binding it
    // create some function so that canvas.style = display none, so that it's not in the way
    // then get the element at the click coordinates
    var ghost = document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    //create an event
    var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
    evt.initEvent(e.type, true, true);
    //set x and y on evt to match the x and y that was used in the original click
    evt.pageX = e.pageX;
    evt.pageY = e.pageY;
    //do the event on the element
    ghost.dispatchEvent(evt);
    // create some function to reshow the canvas. 
}
```

Alternatively, you could hide the specific element if you are trying to click on something behind it on the canvas. Or, you could destroy the canvas completely instead of hiding it if you don't need it after the event happens.